# GCC inline assembly error: Error: junk `(%esp)' after expression

Tags: gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

GCC inline assembly error: Error: junk `(%esp)' after expression

I'm studying gcc inline assembly. My environment is Win 7 32bit, mingw-gcc 4.6.1.

I have got a problem about the 'm' constraint. Here is my c function code:

```
static int asm_test(int a, int b)
{

    int c = 0;
    __asm__ __volatile__(".intel_syntax\n"
            "mov eax, %1\n" //error
            "mov edx, %2\n" //error
            "add eax, edx\n"
            "mov %0, eax\n" //error
            ".att_syntax"
            :"=m"(c)\
            :"m"(a),"m"(b)\
            :"eax","edx"
            );
    return c;
}
```

For at&t code, it is like this:

```
static int asm_test(int a, int b)
{

    int c = 0;
    __asm__ __volatile__(
            "movl %1, $eax\n" //error
            "movl %2, $edx\n" //error
            "addl $edx, $eax\n"
            "movl $eax, %0\n" //error
            :"=m"(c)\
            :"m"(a),"m"(b)\
            :"eax","edx"
            );
    return c;
}
```

For each of the three lines which operate input/output operands, gcc generate an error when compiling, read like this:

C:\Users\farta\AppData\Local\Temp\cc99HxYj.s:22: **Error: junk `(%esp)' after expression**

If i use 'r' for input/output constraint, the code will work. But I cannot understand why it works and what the error stands for. Can anyone tell me? As far as I know 'm' is just telling gcc not to allocate registers but directly access them in memory if inline asm code try to access input/output operands. Is this correct?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not sure you can use Intel syntax in there. Try with AT&T.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried equivalent at&t asm code. The error message are all the same. I think it is not caused by Intel syntax.

Comment: Well show the AT&T syntax. Most people who do GCC inline assemble will be more familiar with that than Intel.

Comment: AT&T syntax is:    __asm__ __volatile__(
            "movl %1, $eax" 
            "movl %2, $edx"
            "addl $edx, $eax"
            "movl $eax, %0"
            :"=m"(c)\
            :"m"(a),"m"(b)\
            :"eax","edx"
            )

Comment: Please edit your question to add the code, it's very hard to read in comments. In general, you should always edit your question when clarifications are requested in comments, so that everyone sees the extra information directly. (There's an "edit" link right under the tags you can use.)

Comment: @farta, this is not AT&T i386 syntax, `$` is for constants, use `%%` in front of register names, like `%%eax`.

Comment: @Mat Thanks a lot. The at&t code has been added.

Comment: @chill It seems I need to read more about the syntax of at&t asm code. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is the GCC generates AT&T syntax construct for `%0`, `%1` and `%2`. If you look at the generated assembly, it looks like:

```
.intel_syntax
mov eax, 8(%ebp)
mov edx, 12(%ebp)
add eax, edx
mov -4(%ebp), eax
```

which is not a valid Intel syntax.

Generally, you don't need to include in the inline assembly explicit load/store operation - just specify register constraint and the compiler will generate loads/stores by itself. This has the advantage that even if your variables (parameters, locals) do not reside in memory at all, but are in registers your code will still be correct - unlike in the case if you explicitly put memory load/stores there.

For your example, try the following code, look at the assembly (`gcc -S`) and notice how the compiler will perform moves from argument area (e.g. stack on x86) all by itself.

```
int asm_test(int a, int b)
{
  __asm__ __volatile__ (
                        ".intel_syntax\n"
                        "add %0, %1 \n"
                        ".att_syntax \n"
                        :"+r"(a)
                        :"r"(b));
  return a;
```

}

Comment: Yeah, your code works. So do you mean most time we should use 'r'? But if our asm code is a little more complex and needs to use some general-purpose registers, we need to know which register gcc are using for each operands before we mix them up. So in this scenario, we should use 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' to explicit tell gcc, is that correct?

Comment: @farta, if you use insns, which require specific registers (like `imul`), yes, but, generally, leave GCC to allocate registers by itself.

Comment: Also, if you want intel syntax inline assembly, switch `gcc` to intel using `-masm=intel`.