# Assembler Error for GCC inline assembly for x86_64 machine(at&t syntax)

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I am trying to read a value from the stack using the gcc inline assembly with the default at&t syntax.
My code is

```
unsigned int ret_val;
__asm volatile(
            "movq %%rbp %0;\n"
            :"=r"(ret_val)
            );
```

I am getting an error:

```
Assembler messages:
Error: junk `%eax' after register
```

What is the meaning of this error and how do I get rid of this.
I already read through some similar questions on SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856792/gcc-inline-assembly-error-error-junk-esp-after-expression) but no help from them.
I am more interested in knowing the cause behind the error and the correct way to do it.

The code is written for x86_64 ubuntu machine.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems. First - you need a comma between registers in mov command:

```
"movq %%rbp, %0;\n"
```

Second, you need 64-bit variable to hold value of `%rbp`. `int` is 32-bit on x86_64 linux. You can use `long` or preferably `uint64_t`.

Comment: My bad that was a terrible mistake